# How to show only elements of list that have one Boolean Value set to False? in c#

Tags: c#, list, if-statement, boolean

I'm quite new to c# so sorry for kinda "noobish" question.

**My main goal is to show **only** unavalible books when I recall the method that handles giving back the books.**

I have a list of items (books) that have values like this:

**Books.cs**

```
 public string author, title;
        public bool avalible;
```

And also i have a class Audiobooks that inherits from class books, like this:

**Audiobooks.cs**

```
public class audiobook : book
{
    public string whoReads;
    public audiobook()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Set a name of  lector: ");
        this.whoReads = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
```

Now in the main class where i handle borrowing/giving back/adding and Displaying all books I want to display **only** unavalible books when I recall the method that handles giving back the books so the user won't choose the book that is already avalible. Then I will just set the `bool avalible` to `true`.

I tried `if(books.Contains(false));` ~there was a problem with converting (CS1503)
I tried something with `foreach` but this din't worked too.
I will be gratefull for all responses. I'm sorry for any gramaticall errors - english is my 2nd language.

Comment: `list.Where(x => !x.available)`?

Comment: @KirkWoll it gives me CS0103 for x

Comment: You included `x` on both sides of the `=>` operator?  That syntax is declaring and using `x` all at once.

Comment: Why not the linq @KirkWoll wrote about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        List<Books> li; // all Books List
        List<Books> li_2;
        var q = from l in li
                where l.available == false
                select l;

        li_2 = q.toList();
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me but i might use the other comment to try and do it without making second list for unavalible books

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you need something like this:

```
List<Books> books = //load data;

foreach (book in books)
{
      if (!book.available)
      {
            //Your code
      }
}
```

Comment: I will try it and give you a feedback